# Finding a suitable transformation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have to find a transformation of $u$ that is of the form $\tilde u=f(t)u$ to reduce my problem

$u_t -ku_{xx} +(vu)_x +cu=0$

to

$\tilde u_t -k\tilde u_{xx} +a\tilde u_x=0$

I'm not really sure what to do, or what kind of problem it is to look it up either. I have a feeling I might have to use $u=e^{t\lambda}$ but that would leave me with $u_x$ and $u_{xx} =0$.

Do I have to substitute my value for $u$ and its derivatives into my original equation to find $\lambda$ and the do something else, I really don't know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert $u=\tilde u/f(t)$ in your equation
$$u_t -ku_{xx} +(vu)_x +cu=0$$
$$\frac{f \tilde u_t - \tilde u f_t}{f(t)^2} - k \tilde u_{xx}/f(t) +(v \tilde u)_x/f(t) +c \tilde u/f(t)=0$$
$$\frac{f \tilde u_t - \tilde u f_t}{f} - k \tilde u_{xx} +(v \tilde u)_x +c \tilde u=0$$
$$\tilde u_t - \tilde u f_t/f - k \tilde u_{xx} +(v \tilde u)_x +c \tilde u=0$$
If $c=f_t/f$ ($c$ is a constant, right?), then
$$\tilde u_t - k \tilde u_{xx} +(v \tilde u)_x=0$$
which has the desired form.

So you need
$$\frac{df}{dt}=c f$$
$$f=\exp(c t)$$

Comment: How did you know you needed $$\frac{df}{dt}=c f$$
$$f=\exp(c t)$$?

Comment: In order to bring the equation in the desired form (which you wrote), you want to cancel the terms $-\tilde u f_t/f$ and $c\tilde u$. So you demand $-\tilde u f_t/f + c\tilde u=0$ and solve for $f$.